# New object created in child context doesn't exist in parent context after saving

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I inserted an object in child context and got the objectID, then I saved both child context and parent context. now I want to get the object through objectID, but I can only get it with child context but parent context, why?

```
...
NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease];
childContext.parentContext = self.parentContext;
[childContext performBlock:^{
    NSManagedObject *obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:childContext];

    if (![childContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

    [self.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        if (![self.parentContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }];

    NSManagedObjectID *objID = [obj ObjectID];
    NSManagedObject *objTmp = [self.parentContext existingObjectWithID:objID error:&error];
    // Why objTmp is nil here?

    NSManagedObjectID *objIDTmp = [[[self.parentContext executeFetchRequest...] objectatindex:0] objectID];
    // objIDTmp is different from objID 
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new object will get a new NSManagedObjectID when it is saved to the permanent store. You can call `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects` to get a permanent id before saving it.

```
[childContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[obj] error:&error];
NSManagedObjectID *objID = [obj ObjectID];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NSManagedObjectID` of a newly created `NSManagedObject` that has not been committed will change after the `save` is performed.

That's the reason you are not able to find the `NSManagedObject` using `objID` after saving the object.

Read [Managed Object IDs and URIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I did save both childContext and parentContext before get the object through objectID, you can check my code.

Comment: Yes and that is why the value of `objID `  will change because you performed `if (![childContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }`. Move `NSManagedObjectID *objID = [obj ObjectID];` just above the line where you fetch it and try.

Comment: I have updated my question, is that what you mean? if so, it still doesn't work....  In fact, I can fetch the object with childContext but parentContext.

Comment: Hi Apoorv, I have some findings, please check my latest question. After saving context, I fetch the object with parentContext, and get the right objectID, which means I can't get right objectID through the object I created, even after saving. So do you know how to deal with this problem, since I don't want to re-fetch after saving...

Comment: Why can't you use `obj` itself?

Comment: I need to pass it to another thread, only objectID is thread safe